# Blue prism Calculator by fetching excel sheet

Tags: calculator, blueprism

I wanted to launch calculator application in which we have to fetch value from excel and update the result back in the excel sheet.
Automate the process using windows application type available in the automation tool.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question?

If you are a beginner and want to know how to start, here you go:

To launch and work with calculator(windows) application - use object studio.
To work with excel ( to read and write back to excel using MS Excel VBO provided by Blueprism).

Create separate action pages (for addition, subtraction, multiply etc.,) in object and publish them and then call those published actions from process studio using Action stage (by passing input values read from excel)

If you can share your exact question - I will be able to help you out.